# Multiple rows in an ARRAY

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Twilio REST API and using it to send a TEXT to everyone from a MySQL database.

Here is what I have so far.. (of the sending the text part)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numbers",$conn);
$people = array(

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        "+1".$row['number'] => $row['name'],
    }
);
```

This does not work obviously, but that is what I am wanting to do.. but can't figure out how.

Here is what I have that works but only sends the first

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numbers",$conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $people = array(
             "+1".$row['number'] => $row['name'],
                   );
}
```

Help!
Chad.

Comment: _This does not work_ and _that is what I am wanting to do_ .. and we should guess?

Comment: @dbf There already exist similar questions where people only wanted to populate an array with the results from the database. (some sort of PDO's `fetchAll` in combination with `array_column`)

Comment: @ChadCardiff there is also this thing about using `mysql_*` functions .. i keep forgetting, but look it up at the PHP manual, it has a red thing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$people = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $people["+1".$row['number']] = $row['name'];
}
```

Is this what you want?

You're everytime overwriting your `$people` variable with a new array, so you'll have only the last row. (not the first)

You have to assign key per key to populate the `$people` array.

Comment: Thank you so much! this was much easier than having to read through all the rude and offensive comments! I'm sure this website is for helping people not offending people. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $people[] = array(
        "+1".$row['number'] => $row['name'],
    );
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense? a two-dim array? here?!